# Java TextField - Custom Picture / Look

Tags: java, image, swing, jtextfield

I am making a game, and i want a place where users can fill out a form suggesting ideas or bugs, but want it to look similar to the rest of the game graphics/buttons etc.. I dont know how to make custom TextFields with pictures. I want the end result to look like this: [image: http://imgur.com/fdvqFNg]

I know how to set up custom buttons and custom labels, not TextFeilds,

So Can anyone tell me how to easily format a JTextFeild with an image icon or something.

Thanks

Comment: Unless you really want to play around with the UI delegate UI, you could start by removing the borders of the text fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is custom about that? Are you talking about:

1. no borders, then just use setBorder(null);
2. semi-transparent look, then use `setBackground( new Color(...) );` - read the Color API for the way to create transparent colors. Also you will need to check out [Backgrounds With Transparency](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) since you can't just use a transparent background directly.

I can't tell if there are any other differences.

Comment: Thanks this will work, but for future reference: what if i want the background to be a picture of a rainbow or maybe a kitty?

Comment: A kitty in a JTextField? The picture wouldn't be very big. Most people would extend the JTextField to do custom painting. That is too involved to describe in a comment. Another approach is to use something like the [BackgroundPanel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/)

Comment: ok and.. it i used "text.setBackground(new Color(255,255,255,80));" and it causes werid glitches like as you type the transparency goes up (too 100%) and there is like "ghost" characters and cursors. Example: http://imgur.com/a1N4oHm (I Typed: "Hello The Dark Llama"), and one more thing, the transparency goes down around 20% when you minimize the window, and re-open it.

Comment: I know it cause painting artifacts, that is why I gave you the link to read.